# How to filter on a value nested deeply in a complex array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I am trying to filter a multi-nested complex array of objects on a specific value. For example, I want to filter a car models array according to the incoming parameter, say "bmw". The expected output should be an array of top level objects which has the incoming parameter (i.e. "bmw" here) as a value in any position of the complex object.

I have tried several approaches without success and I have posted two attempts below together with the output received.

Is there something wrong with my approach or is it my code?

```js
    const arr = [
      {
      id:"1",
      name:"name1",
      assets: [
          {
          cars: {
              brand : [
                  {
                      model: "bmw"
                  },
                  {
                      model: "dodge"
                  }
              ]
          }
          }
      ],
      assets: [
          {
          cars: {
              brand : [
                  {
                      model: "ford"
                  },
                  {
                      model: "ferrari"
                  }
              ]
          }
          }
      ],
      },{
      id:"2",
      name:"name2",
      assets: [
          {
          cars: {
              brand : [
                  {
                      model: "audi"
                  },
                  {
                      model: "maseratti"
                  }
              ]
          }
          }
      ],
      assets: [
          {
          cars: {
              brand : [
                  {
                      model: "mercedes"
                  },
                  {
                      model: "bmw"
                  }
              ]
          }
          }
      ],
      }
    ]
```

If we use, for example:

***let search="bmw"***

then the expected output would be the following array of objects:

```js
    [
      {
      id:"1",
      name:"name1",
      assets: [
          {
          cars: {
              brand : [
                  {
                      model: "bmw"
                  },
                  {
                      model: "dodge"
                  }
              ]
          }
          }
      ],
      },
      {
          id:"2",
          name:"name2",
          assets: [
          {
              cars: {
                  brand : [
                      {
                          model: "mercedes"
                      },
                      {
                          model: "bmw"
                      }
                  ]
              }
          }
          ],
      }
    ]
```

Attempt 1:

```js
const arr = [{ id: "1", name: "name1", assets: [{ cars: { brand: [{ model: "bmw" }, { model: "dodge" } ] } }], assets: [{ cars: { brand: [{ model: "ford" }, { model: "ferrari" } ] } }],}, { id: "2", name: "name2", assets: [{ cars: { brand: [{ model: "audi" }, { model: "maseratti" } ] } }], assets: [{ cars: { brand: [{ model: "mercedes" }, { model: "bmw" } ] } }],}];

let search="bmw"
let filtered= [];
arr.filter((person)=>{
    person.assets.filter((car) => {
        car.cars.brand.filter((m) => {
            if(m.model.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())) {
                filtered.push(m)
            }
        })
    })
});

console.log(arr);

/*********** console output:

[{
    assets: [{
        cars: {
            brand: [{
                model: "ford"
            }, {
                model: "ferrari"
            }]
        }
    }],
    id: "1",
    name: "name1"
}, {
    assets: [{
        cars: {
            brand: [{
                model: "mercedes"
            }, {
                model: "bmw"
            }]
        }
    }],
    id: "2",
    name: "name2"
}]

***********/
```

Attempt 2:

```js
const arr = [{ id: "1", name: "name1", assets: [{ cars: { brand: [{ model: "bmw" }, { model: "dodge" } ] } }], assets: [{ cars: { brand: [{ model: "ford" }, { model: "ferrari" } ] } }],}, { id: "2", name: "name2", assets: [{ cars: { brand: [{ model: "audi" }, { model: "maseratti" } ] } }], assets: [{ cars: { brand: [{ model: "mercedes" }, { model: "bmw" } ] } }],}];

let search="bmw"
const q = arr.filter((element) => {
element.assets.filter((element1) => {
    element1.cars.brand.filter((m) => 
        m.model.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
        .map(element=> {
            return Object.assign({}, element, {element1});
        })
    })
})

console.log(q);

/*********** console output:

[]

************/
```

Comment: JavaScript objects cannot have duplicate keys, you have double assets key it's an error?

Comment: I changed the field names of the object while transferring it here, please don't get hung up on it

Comment: You have two code snippets that don't work. Have you tried debugging them using your debugger? [_StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story._](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Then fix it so we have the right code where to start.

Comment: Of course I tried, but I wrote it here because I couldn't find any meaning.

Comment: What have you found out using your debugger? Which line doesn't behave as you expect? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing or a code debugging service.

Comment: Yes, you have code that doesn't work. The next step is debugging it to find the problem: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). That's one of the most important steps in software development. Debugging is one of the most important skills of a software developer. You won't learn how to write complex code, asking other people while avoiding to debug your code.

Comment: If you read the second sentence of the title, you will understand that my purpose is not just to write the code.

Comment: There is no return statement in the outer filter function in the second snippet. The filter can't return anything. There is also no return statement in the first code snippet. Why do you use filter without return statement? A filter function is expected to return a truthy value for elements you want to keep and a falsy value for elements you want to remove.

Comment: While there are many solutions like this on stackoverflow, it is surprising to get such a response in my question when I wrote it.

Comment: Also, although the questions were very simple from the ones I asked, nobody wrote a sentence such as "Stack Overflow isn't a code writing or a code debugging" service.

Comment: _Of course I tried, but I wrote it here because I couldn't find any meaning._ You can't have two assets key in same object, start to write a good snippet so i can help you.

Comment: According to your example, you want to filter the elements of `arr`. The filter `arr.filter((person)=>{` should contain a logic that checks whether you want to keep that element or remove it and it should return a truthy or falsy value. It is unclear from your example whether you want to filter `assets` and this detail is also missing in the description. There is only one element in each `assets` array. It looks like you don't want to filter `brand`, because the expected result contains all brands. You specification is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having corrected the initially given `arr` structure, a solution is to drill into the structure with an outer call to `.filter` and inner calls to `.some`:

[MDN Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[MDN Some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id:"1",
    name:"name1",
    assets: [
      {
        cars: {
          brand : [
            { model: "bmw" },
            { model: "dodge" },
            { model: "ford" },
            { model: "ferrari" }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    id:"2",
    name:"name2",
    assets: [
      {
        cars: {
          brand : [
            { model: "audi" },
            { model: "maseratti" },
            { model: "mercedes" }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
  }
];



function filterUsersByCar(carBrand, users) {
  return users.filter((user) => {
    const carAssets = user.assets.find((asset) => 'cars' in asset);
    return carAssets && carAssets.cars.brand.some(({ model }) => {
      return model === carBrand;
    });
  });
}

console.log(filterUsersByCar('bmw', arr));
```

*Some things to note:*

The inner `carAssets` is needed because the given `arr` structure implies that it *might be possible* that a user has something *different* than car models inside `assets`. This would mean that a script first has to find out if any of the items in `assets` deals with cars. The shown solution uses the logik "if any of the `assets` items has a field 'cars', the whole item is about cars". This leads to "if there is no 'cars' asset, the whole user should be excluded from the result set". I hope that is *right*.

If the user can only have assets that are cars, it might be possible to simplify the user structure (read: "item in `arr`") such that the `assets` property *directly* includes the objects which are currently placed inside `assets.cars.brand`. That would also remove the need for the `hasCarAssets` check. If that is an option, it would change the solution to:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id:"1",
    name:"name1",
    assets: [
      { model: "bmw" },
      { model: "dodge" },
      { model: "ford" },
      { model: "ferrari" }
    ],
  },
  {
    id:"2",
    name:"name2",
    assets: [
      { model: "audi" },
      { model: "maseratti" },
      { model: "mercedes" }
    ],
  }
];



function filterUsersByCar(carBrand, users) {
  return users.filter((user) => {
    return user.assets.some(({ model }) => model === carBrand);
  });
}

console.log(filterUsersByCar('bmw', arr));
```